# Input length gives undefined on using $scope on ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. But, couldn't find one-line or simple solution.
I am trying to achieve "Characters remaining" count on an input text box but the value of `explorationObjectiveService.displayed` is `undefined`. Help appreciated.

HTML

```
<input id="explorationObjective" type="text"
                   class="form-control protractor-test-exploration-objective-input"
                   ng-model="explorationObjectiveService.displayed"
                   ng-blur="saveExplorationObjective()" placeholder="Learn how to ..." maxlength="100">
```

Directive JS

```
$scope.counter= 100 - ($scope.explorationObjectiveService.displayed).length;
```

Comment: wrong parenthesis: ($scope.explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length);

Comment: The parenthesis won't affect anything @Groben

Comment: Add directive script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this sinppest may helps you....

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.num=100;
  $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.num=100-$scope.data.length
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input id="explorationObjective" type="text"
                   class="form-control protractor-test-exploration-objective-input"
                   ng-model="data"
                   ng-change="change()" placeholder="Learn how to ..." maxlength="100">
                   <p>remained: {{num }}chars</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.